How best to avoid overwriting library source files from Spyder?
I have Anaconda installed with a Python 3.9 environment under my personal user account on Windows.   I use runfile to run a *.py file from the Spyder console.  I normally have the Spyder editor closed and use Cygwin and Vim tabs/subwindows to do anything text related.
When runfile encounters an error, the Spyder editor window opens.  I usually close it right away, but sometimes, I'm just trying to maintain mental flow in getting a code pattern to work via trial and error.  At some point, an error caused the following file to open:
/c/Users/User.Name/AppData/Local/anaconda3/envs/py39/Lib/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py

This creates a hazard in that I may inadvertently make some changes in merge.py, e.g., if keyboard focus not where I thought it was.  However, I would never deliberately save any changes to the source file in a library.
It seems like changes were made anyway, and I assume that I made them.  I don't know how they got saved.  Maybe when I pressed Ctrl+D in the Spyder console to clean out the Variable Explorer, it saves the file to which the text editor is opened (I'm not really sure).  The result is that merge.py has a missing block of code
if rk is not None:
    <...Here belongs the missing code...>
else:
    # work-around for merge_asof(right_index=True)
    right_keys.append(right.index)
if lk is not None and lk == rk:  # FIXME: what about other NAs?
    # avoid key upcast in corner case (length-0)
    lk = cast(Hashable, lk)

Fortunately, I was able to use Cygwin's find to locate an almost identical merge.py:
/c/Users/User.Name/AppData/Local/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py

To prevent this from happening again, I am tempted make all files read-only by issuing one of the following in /c/Users/User.Name/AppData/Local/anaconda3:
chmod -R u-w *
find * -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod u-w

However, I do need to update Anaconda or install packages.  Even if I didn't, I am not sure if Anaconda, Conda, or Python needs write access.  Or any of the packages that I installed to get Apache Spark functionality.  I am relatively new to Python, Anaconda, and Spark.
What is best practice for avoiding what I assume is inadvertent modificaton of library source files?

it is strange that you use runfile to run code. Usually IDEs have some shortcut (like F5) to run new interpreter of python with new script - something like python.exe script.py.

I'm highly reliant on Vim and it's interaction with Bash. I'm usually navigating quite a few text files at the same time. But I think the risk of modifying library source files may still exist even if I didn't use Vim. Apart from that, I'm learning Python and Pandas, so I need the REPL to experiment with variables and code after the *.py file has run.

I never saw in any IDE automatically opening files. Besides most of Python's libraries I have in global folder which is restricted by file privileges - they are read-only - so when I want to (re)write library then system blocks access. Maybe you should also block files as read-only. On Linux it needs command chmod (CHange MODe) in shell - chmod -w filename (-w means not-writable, +w means writable). You can also use * to change many files at once. Maybe there is also option -r for recursion to run code also in subfolders.

I didn't open the file myself. I close the editor by default. Sometimes I leave it open but never use it. Also, I wouldn't know how to navigate to a library source file. I appreciate your suggestion to use chmod. I speak to that in the posted question but erroneously wrote it as -r instead of -w (corrected now).

I think I know what caused the window to open to a library source file.  I clicked within the console window to shift focus to it.  I just happened to click on a message of a Traceback for an exception.  It turned out to be a file path.
